# Inequalities between exponential means

Tags: inequality, means

When considering a vector $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ the root-mean-power 
$$M_\alpha=(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^\alpha)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$
for $\alpha$ a real number $\neq 0$ is known to be such that 
$$M_\alpha \leq M_\beta$$
for any $\beta > \alpha$, with equality if and only if $x_1=\ldots=x_n$. I was wondering if it was known whether a similar inequality holds for the exponential mean, written as
$$EM_\alpha= \frac{1}{\alpha}\ln(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i})?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to substitute $e^x$ for $x$ and take the logarithm.